# PHP - Refresh a partial page as php using Ajax

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, include

I am trying to refresh a partial page which is a php file which I include. In that php file is also the ajax function which calls a specific url and refresh the page: See the example:

PHP-File called by the user via the browser

```html
<div id="divBox">
  <? include ( "file.php"); ?>
</div>
```

File.php

```js
$.ajax({
  url: "url/bla/xxx.php",
  success: function(result) {
    $("#divBox").html(result);
  }
});
```

```html
<div>
  <? echo $var1->attr; ?>
</div>
```

And last file: xxx.php (which is called from ajax)

```html
´ //do some stuff
<? include ( "file.php"); ?>
```

Would that be work? Or is there a better way to do that?

I hope this example suffice to understand what I am trying to do?

Thank you.

Comment: "Would that be work?"... Why don't you simply try it? And no, it won't work, at least not as expected. Ask yourself that question: _when_ should the AJAX request be made?

Comment: Sure I tried it and i did not work ;). I know that AJAX is client side. But if I instead of include(file.php) use echo "hi", it will say hi in the divBox. So I thought that the "result" of the include-command would be in the result var of the success function. But how you would do it? If you need to refresh a part of the page and you do not want to use JavaScript for manipulate html code?

Comment: Slightly off-topic, but you can use `<?= $var ?>` instead of `<? echo $var ?>` when displaying a variable inside HTML like you are

Comment: AJAX _is_ javascript. There is no way around using javascript for client side action. It is impossible to do that by server side means.

Comment: But there is also the jquery load method! $("#divBox").load('file.php'); . Would that work or what is the load function do?